# CSS>ФОН>КАРТИНКА

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! Проконсультируйте по следующей проблеме. Хочу добиться эффекта , когда при большом объеме информации на сайте, при скроле, фоновая картинка, будто вытягивалась(без искажений) на высоту всего имеющегося текста, и внизу страницы логически заканчивалась.Например, как тут http://wot.igromania.ru/ Обратите внимание на фон 
У меня имеется готовая картинка для фона(рисовал сам в PS). Размер ее довольно большой. Нужно ли заранее уменьшать размер и где это лучше сделать: в коде? или непосредственно в редакторе(PS). Какие размеры в пределах нормы нужно задавать, что бы на разных мониторах. И собственно как добиться эффекта такого растяжения.Разрезать ее на 3 части, фиксировать верх и низ, а середине задавать значения в зависимости от информации? тогда как избавиться от артефактов на стыках?!

Comment: В шапке - одна фоновая картинка, а в подвале - вторая. Фоном в body - цвет. Это что касается сайта, который вы привели, как пример.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо подбирать бесшовные фон или текстуру. Если уже используете большую картинку - 
обработайте картинку - до наименьшего размера - но чтоб не сильно качесто ушло.

http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-repeat почитайте это надеюсь поможет

Comment: СПАСИБО!!
то есть взять div для верхней части фона и закрепить, так же для нижней, а для середины div сделать зависящем от объема информации??? это вообще реально? ведь само содержимое страницы будет в отдельном divе. 
ps. в этом деле дилетант, так что, прошу прощения, если несу чушь

Comment: @Валентин882, у меня сложилось ощущение, что ваши вопросы адресованны ко мне, в связи с комментарием выше. Только почему-то, вы ответ написали тут. )

В общем, если одним словом, то да. Всё это относится к вопросу "верстки", с которой, возможно, вы даже не знакомы, а стоило бы. Но на сегодняшний день, это еще реальней, т.к. появилась возможность, делать такие вещи с помощью CSS (CSS3, если быть точнее). Попробуйте поискать в гугле, что-нибудь по запросу [Мульти бэкграунд][1]...

   [1]:https://www.google.ru/search?q=Мульти+бэкграунд